# Динамическое изменение background сайта

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc

При открытии любой страницы на моем сайте с помощью javascript для тега body проставляется параметр background с рандомным значением:

```
$(function () {
    var rand = Math.floor((Math.random() * 17) + 1);
    $("body").css("background", "url(../Images/backgrounds/back_" + rand + ".jpg) no-repeat fixed 50% 0 rgb(20,20,20)");
    $("body").css("background-size", "cover");
    $("body").css("position", "relative");
});
```

Мне не очень нравится это решение, так как выполнение данной функции занимает приличное количество времени.
Вопрос, собственно, как сделать лучше и правильней.

Сайт на ASP.NET MVC, может возможно как-то это сделать в контроллере или во View? Хотя наверно этот вариант не подойдет, т.к есть несколько контроллеров

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Стили нужно вернуть раньше, чтобы они не на js добавлялись после того как документ загрузится. А изначально были встроены в head.

`rand` значение нужно получить на стороне сервера и на основе него стили добавить внутрь `<head><style></style></head>`. Т.е. view должен получиться вроде такого:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com...."></script>
  <style>
    body {
      background: url(../Images/backgrounds/back_@randId.jpg) no-repeat fixed 50% 0 rgb(20,20,20);
      background-size: cover;
      position: relative;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
....
</body>
```

Comment: возможно стоит написать класс для каждой картинки и изменять в javascript параметр класса у body?

Comment: @tCode Можно и так. Но опять же картинка начнёт загружаться после того как js отработает..

Comment: "Стили нужно вернуть раньше" - можно конкретный пример?

Comment: @tCode добавил в ответ. Т.е. ваш общий layout который выводит `<head>` должен еще ваши дополнительные стили вывести..

Comment: а вы не ошиблись, написав скрипт в теге <style>?

Comment: @tCode да, вы правы. Имел в виду голый css вставить, исправил..

Comment: Еее)) Работает, спасибо